Spare wheel looks identical to others, is it?
I have a ford fiesta. The spare wheel likes like the other wheels (same size, same everything). However it has a sticker on it, with a maximum speed of 50Miles/hour 80km/h.
It this wheel different?, what is limitation for?

Year: 2003 (model made 2002 to ????)
Make: Ford
Model: Fiesta
Variant: fujb1


While the tire may look the same, it probably isn't. The regular tires on your Fiesta are most likely small. Looking at what should be available on them (from this website), it appears the most common size is 175/65R14 across the different available models. If this is the size of your regular tires, a spare could easily be of the same basic size. Most donut spares will have the words "TEMPORARY" or "SPARE TIRE" embossed on sidewall to let you know that's what they are. If the wheel of your spare tire has a sticker on it stating it's a spare, I'd suggest you treat it as a spare.
Spare tires are built much differently than regular tires. They don't have the side or tread plies, nor the tread depth or consistency. They are built much lighter than regular tires and are only meant to get you from where a regular tire goes flat to somewhere you can get it repaired or replaced. They aren't meant for extended use or higher speeds.
